# Why do I get a linker error while I try to compile a C file?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, clang

I've had this error for weeks I already made a post about it but it wasn't very clear.
So I am calling a function from a a header file myBmpGris.h and the functions are implemented on the file myBmpGris.c . Here is my main file:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include "myBmpGris.h"

int main(){

    char * image_name = "image_carre.bmp";
    BmpImg image = readBmpImage(image_name);

 return 0;
```

I compile by using `ggc main.c` and I get this error message :

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_readBmpImage", referenced from:
>         _main in main-1c453a.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I read a lot of posts about the same error message but none of the answers seem to apply to my case. I'm kind of desperate because a lot of my programs give me the same error. What should I do ?

Comment: Include how you compile and which parameters you use.

Comment: What did all the other answers suggest? Add the library? Where are the functions implemented that you are using? Remember: A header is no library....

Comment: Is `ggc main.c` how you write in the terminal? In that case, you're missing the source file for "myBmpGris" when you compile

Comment: I compile by writing gcc main.c in the terminal.

Comment: Where is the implementation of the function `readBmpImage()` in your opinion?

Comment: As I said all the other answers are very specific to the code the question showed. I used the libraries stdio.h and stdlib.h. and all my functions are implemented in myBmpGris.c

Comment: And how do you compile that file myBmpGris.c?  Or to put it differently, have you tried telling the compiler about that other file? E.g. `gcc main.c myBmpGris.c` .

Comment: I didn't compile myBmpGris.c because it's where the functions of myBmpGris.h are implemented and I use these functions in my main file.

Comment: If you implement anything there, then you need to also compile it. Did you try as I proposed?

Comment: Oh thanks a lot it works @Yunnosch you should put your comment as an answer

Comment: "I used the libraries stdio.h and stdlib.h." As I mentioned a few comments above: Remember: A header is no library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler about all the code files which contain any of the needed functions.

So if you have until now compiled like `gcc main.c`, then the simplest way of also getting the other file compiled is `gcc main.c myBmpGris.c`.

You might want to read up on the other things you can helpfully tell the compiler (and other parts of the building), i.e. the possible commandline parameters. Or use one of the available free programming environments. (I am not going to name any. Just use your favorite search engine on "C IDE free" or similar. The first few hits discuss several, try a few, then use the one your friends use, or the one you really like much, much better.)

Answer (score 1):

There are two thing.

1. Compilation   you have included. h file. It means comilper will make entry in symbol table for all used function from included library.
2. Linking  here linker try to get address from library to fill in symbol table created in first step. This cannot be performed in your case. So give full path of library.